# Regex redirect gets caught in infinite loop

Tags: regex, wordpress

So, I'm trying to get any URL that starts with `'locations'` and ends exactly 4 levels deep to append /1 onto the end, e.g

`http://example.com/locations/lorem/ipsum/dolor` should go to 
`http://example.com/locations/lorem/ipsum/dolor/1`

I've got the following which I thought was correct, but seems to give me an infinite redirect loop:

FROM: `locations/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)`

TO: `locations/$1/$2/$3/1`

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: ...can whoever downvoted this perhaps explain why? I thought it was very clearly written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't restrict the pattern sufficiently.

```
http://example.com/locations/lorem/ipsum/dolor/1
                   ||||||||||           |     |
                   locations/(.+       )/(.+ )/(.+)
```

```
http://example.com/locations/lorem/ipsum/dolor/1/1
                   ||||||||||                 | |__
                   ||||||||||                 |    |
                   locations/(.+             )/(.+)/(.+)
```

```
http://example.com/locations/lorem/ipsum/dolor/1/1/1
                   ||||||||||                   | |__
                   ||||||||||                   |    |
                   locations/(.+               )/(.+)/(.+)
```

So replace

```
locations/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)
```

with one of the following depending on the regex dialect used:

```
locations/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\z    # Perl, PCRE, ...
```

or

```
locations/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$     # JavaScript, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

(.+) will match any char untill .../dolor/. That's why you are probably getting infinite loop.

You can probably consider using /[a-z]/ to parse each subset from your URL